# Bounded $g(z)=f(z)f(\frac{1}{z})$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ for non-constant entire $f$. Find the $f(z)$ satisfying the below conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> For a non-constant entire function $f(z)$, let $g(z)=f(z)f(\frac{1}{z})$.
> $g(z)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Then show $f(0)=0$. Plus find the $f(z)$ when the $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2i$.

I solved this by different way compared with in my solution book. I can't ensure my solution is right or not. From here my solution starts.

$g$ has the removable singularities at $z=0$. Say $f(z)= (a_0 + a_1z +a_2z^2+\cdots)$

Considering the Laurent series of $g(z) = (a_0 + a_1z +a_2z^2+\cdots)(a_0 + a_1(1/z) +a_2(1/z^2)+\cdots)$

If $f$ has infinite terms, $g$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. Therefore, $f$ has a finite terms .(In other words $f$ is polynomial, $f(z)= a_0 + a_1z +a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n$ with $a_n \neq 0$.)

Again, I took the Laurent series $g(z) = (a_0 + a_1z +a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n)(a_0 + a_1(1/z) +a_2(1/z^2)+\cdots+a_n(1/z^n))$. If we suppose $a_0\neq0$, $g(z)$ has $n$-th pole at $z=0$ from the reason $a_n\neq0$. It contradicts the fact that $g$ has a removable at $z=0$. So $a_0=0$.

Therefore, I found $f(z) = iz^2 + a_3z^3+\cdots+a_nz^n$ from the given conditions $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2i$.

Since $g$ doesn't have negative degree terms $a_n=0 , n\geq3$ (If not, $g$ has the pole at $z=0$ )

Final answer is $f(z)=iz^2$

My answer is right when I've checked it. But I have a doubt for process for deducing it. Is my solution right?

Comment: You meant $f(z)=iz^2$. Yes your solution is right.

Comment: @reuns ah there was typo. Thank you